# New .NET Core SDK Project Type - Debug COM Add-in not possible?

Tags: c#, com, visual-studio-debugging, visual-studio-2019, excel-addins

I recently upgraded to .NET Framework 4.8 on a legacy project, and think I've discovered a limitation with the Visual Studio 2019 Debugger and/or the new .NET Core SDK project type.

Below is the before and after of the csproj:

## Before

ExcelAddin.MyRtdServer.csproj

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="12.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == '' ">Debug</Configuration>
    <Platform Condition=" '$(Platform)' == '' ">AnyCPU</Platform>
    <ProjectGuid>{572DAC9C-DC52-425A-83F2-6EF0EB4FF2BC}</ProjectGuid>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <AssemblyName>ExcelAddin.MyExcelRtdServer</AssemblyName>
    <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.8</TargetFrameworkVersion>
    <ApplicationVersion>1.0.0.0</ApplicationVersion>
    <FileAlignment>512</FileAlignment>
    <RootNamespace>ExcelAddin.MyExcelRtdServer</RootNamespace>
    <FileUpgradeFlags>
    </FileUpgradeFlags>
    <UpgradeBackupLocation>
    </UpgradeBackupLocation>
    <OldToolsVersion>3.5</OldToolsVersion>
    <TargetFrameworkProfile />
    <NuGetPackageImportStamp>
    </NuGetPackageImportStamp>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Debug\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG;TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
    <RegisterForComInterop>true</RegisterForComInterop>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release|AnyCPU' ">
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <DebugType>pdbonly</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
    <OutputPath>bin\Release\</OutputPath>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE</DefineConstants>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <Prefer32Bit>false</Prefer32Bit>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>MyStrongName.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.15.0.4795.1000\lib\net20\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll</HintPath>
      <EmbedInteropTypes>True</EmbedInteropTypes>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.Linq" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data" />
    <Reference Include="System.Core" />
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="..\GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs">
      <Link>Properties\GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs</Link>
    </Compile>
    <Compile Include="MyRtdServer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\Settings.Designer.cs" />
    <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="App.config" />
    <None Include="packages.config" />
    <None Include="MyStrongName.snk" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

ExcelAddin.MyRtdServer.csproj.user

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="Current" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <StartAction>Program</StartAction>
    <StartProgram>C:\Program Files %28x86%29\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE</StartProgram>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ProjectView>ShowAllFiles</ProjectView>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

## After

ExcelAddin.MyRtdServer.csproj

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Authors>John Zabroski</Authors>
    <Description>ExcelAddin.MyExcelRtdServer .NET Assembly</Description>
    <Copyright>Copyright © 2019</Copyright>
    <SignAssembly>true</SignAssembly>
    <AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>MyStrongName.snk</AssemblyOriginatorKeyFile>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Remove="appSettings.xml" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="..\GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs" Link="Properties\GlobalAssemblyInfo.cs" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="appSettings.xml">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel" Version="15.0.4795.1000" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.Configuration" />
    <Reference Include="System.Data.Linq" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

launchSettings.json

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "ExcelAddin.MyRtdServer": {
      "commandName": "Executable",
      "executablePath": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Office\\root\\Office16\\EXCEL.EXE"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: No support for registering the add-in.  Painful.  So you forgot to do it by hand?

Comment: I registered the add-in manually using RegAsm.exe /tlb and /codebase.  Just assume I did the ordinary bookkeeping correctly.

Comment: I suppose it's possible the `RegAsm.exe /unregister my.dll` may have been wrong due to previously registering under `bin/Debug/` vs `bin/Debug/net48/`. I'll look more into this.

Answer (score 0):

Excel-DNA doesn't support the new SDK-style project at the moment, and we are working on adding support for an upcoming version of Excel-DNA.

You can track the following issues to get notified on progress on that front:

- [Update ExcelDna.AddIn NuGet Package to support the new PackageReference format #193](https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna/issues/193)
- [Update ExcelDna.Integration NuGet Package to support the new PackageReference format #188](https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna/issues/188)
- [ExcelDna.AddIn NuGet package installation fails as a PackageReference #138](https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna/issues/138)

Comment: I'm asking more generally about debugging under these conditions.  I suspect you'll run into this general debuggability problem once you resolve those other issues, which are unrelated to debugging.

Comment: @JohnZabroski I didn't see any issues debugging. The main difference is how you tell VS2019 to find EXCEL.EXE (`launchSettings.json` instead of `Project.csproj.user`), which is why Excel-DNA build SetDebuggerOptions doesn't work for SDK-style projects at the moment

Comment: I updated the question to demonstrate that even with launchSettings.json and Project.csproj.user correctly set-up, the issue still happens.

Comment: He uses Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel, that doesn't sound much like  DNA.

Comment: I actually have multiple variations of this in a legacy project.  One approach uses the DLL.  I should probably clean it up and remove the reference to that DLL entirely and just use COM interfaces.

Comment: @HansPassant I came across this question because John opened an [issue in the Excel-DNA repo](https://github.com/Excel-DNA/ExcelDna/issues/278). I assumed he was trying to migrate to Excel-DNA.